# Modernizr toString

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Why does [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/v2.6.1/modernizr.js#L54) do the following:

```
toString = {}.toString,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's grabbing a local copy of the `Object.prototype.toString` method which would allow it to make small speed improvements in the script. This also allows it to test that the `toString` method exists.

Regards to comments:

Every name resolution there is a cost, in lookup-time (locals, globals, prototype-chaining) and creation (closure-scoped variable), so imaging the following code:

```
var values = // Create some object here.

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  console.log(values[i].toString());
}
```

For each iteration of the look we are having to resolve the `values` variable, and walk the prototype chain to identify the member `toString`, and then execute that.

Taking that above example, we could do the following:

```
var toString = {}.toString,
    values = // Create some object here.

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  console.log(toString.call(values[i]));
}
```

Or even further:

```
var toString = {}.toString,
    log = console.log,
    values = // Create some object here.

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  log.call(console, toString.call(values[i]));
}
```

Light applications won't really benefit too much from this, but larger frameworks, such as jQuery, etc, can improve the script performance quite significantly. IE I believe is one such browser where these small improvements can help quite a lot.

Comment: improvements due to avoiding the travel up and down the prototype chain (of the `Modernizr` object)?

Comment: There is an inherent danger in caching members this way, and comes down to expected application behaviour. Example, you cache `Object.prototype.toString`, but then implement a custom `toString` method, e.g. `{ toString: fuction() { return "Hello World"; } }`. Would you expect when calling `toString.call(...)` on your custom object to execute your custom `toString` method?

Comment: @MatthewAbbott That's exactly why Modernizer takes the `toString` implementation from `Object`: it doesn't want to execute custom versions, it *needs* to call the default implementation so it can parse the type in the result. For example, to check if `d` is a `Date`, you can't check `d.toString()` since it formats the date. Instead, you need to use `({}).toString.call(d)` which returns `"[object Date]"`, allowing you to check the type. Since many DOM element types are not exposed in JavaScript as global variables, you cannot use `instanceof` so this is the only way to check for them.

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether under the given environment there is a toString property defined by default on an object. It doesn't do it on a new Object() because the Object may not itself be defined in the environment.